# Meet an error in IF statement in mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to update the quantity of people in supermarket by mysql. Supermarket is the table. Person means the quantity of people in the supermarket. N means the name of the supermarket. Decrease means the number of decreasing quantity in the supermarket. If the quantity of people in the supermarket is less than 100, then set the person to be 100. This mysql command returns that "error 1193 unknown system variable 'person'". Any suggestion please?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updatePerson(IN n CHAR(10), IN decrease INT)
BEGIN
 UPDATE supermarket
 SET person = person - decrease 
 WHERE name = n;

 IF person< 100 THEN 
  SET person  = 100;
 END IF;
END
```

Comment: Seems you just stuck an `IF` statement after a semi-related query and expected it to magically work.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updatePerson(IN n CHAR(10), IN decrease INT)
BEGIN
 UPDATE supermarket
 SET person =case when (person - decrease) <100 then 100 else  (person - decrease) end 
 WHERE name = n;    
END
```

Try that.